# How to pass parameters from jQuery to laravel route

Tags: jquery, laravel

Im trying to pass an integer parameter to a laravel method. I can't seem to get the format right in the jQuery?

Route method

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */

public function appendMediaImage($adid){
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ads_images = Media::whereUserId($user_id)->whereAdId($adid)->whereRef('ad')->get();

    return view('admin.append_media', compact('ads_images'));
}
```

jQuery

```
if (data.success == 1){
                        $('#uploaded-ads-image-wrap').load('{{ route('append_media_image','adid':'50') }}');
                    } else{
                        alert("fail");
                        toastr.error(data.msg, '<?php echo trans('app.error') ?>', toastr_options);
                    }
```

Route definition

```
Route::get('append-media-image', ['as'=>'append_media_image', 'uses' => 'AdsController@appendMediaImage']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route) helper should be an array defining the parameters for the route.

You can do it this way instead:

```
$('#uploaded-ads-image-wrap').load('{{ route('append_media_image', ['adid' => 50]) }}');
```

Edit: You also need to change your route to cater for the `adid` parameter.

```
Route::get('append-media-image/{adid}', 'AdsController@appendMediaImage')->name('append_media_image');
```

Comment: I did try that, but I got the following error. Its like there is no parameter being passed - Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdsController::appendMediaImage(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected.

Comment: Can we see your route definition?

Comment: I have updated the post. Im very new to Laravel! Hopefully this is the route definition!